# Setting a cookie based on a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a conditional that sets a cookie based on whether a selector exists. There are other places in the code where I do something similar if the selector exists. If the selector exists I either add "nfl" or "nfl-" (notice the dash) to various attributes on the page. I'm trying to remove as much code as I can as there are about five other places I have similar code where I'm adding other attributes. I also feel like there's a better way to approach this without having to write this a ton of times:

```
if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
```

I'm banging my head on how to condense this but can't figure this out. Please include code samples; I learn best that way.

```
if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
    var user_cookie = {
    name: 'nfl-user-profile',
    options: {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    }
    };
} else {
    var user_cookie = {
    name: 'user-profile',
    options: {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    }
    };
}

if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
$('header').attr("href","#nfl-city");
$('header').attr("href","#nfl-state");
} else {
$('header').attr("href","#city");
$('header').attr("href","#state");
}

if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
$('footer').attr("title","#nflcity");
$('footer').attr("title","#nflstate");
} else {
$('footer').attr("title","#city");
$('footer').attr("title","#state");
}
```

Comment: <header> is an html5 element. Sorry the second conditional was suppose to be <footer>

Comment: When you call `attr(name,value)` twice in a row like that on the same selector, doesn't the second value overwrite the first value?

Comment: I agree with @ChrisW. I also think that setting the `title` attribute to a user-unfriendly string makes little sense. (Wouldn't the browser treat it as a tooltip?) Could you explain the meaning behind `.userLocation` and `nfl-`, and what the motivation for this code is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is that wrap the condition:

```
var hasUserLocation = function (hasFunc, noFunc) {
    if ($(".userLocation").size() > 0) {
        hasFunc();
    } else {
        noFunc();
    }
}
```

then you can call like this:

```
hasUserLocation(function () {
    alert("has");
}, function () {
    alert("no")
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWgpq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Increase DRYness.  Something like this:

```
var makeAnchor = function(prefix, suffix) {
    return "#" + prefix + suffix;
}

var nflPrefix = "nfl-";
if ($(".userLocation").length > 0) { nflPrefix = "nfl"; }
$('header').attr("href", makeAnchor(nflPrefix, "city");
```

The ternary operator may be suitable too: `var nflPrefix = "nfl" + ($(".userLocation").length > 0 ? "-" : "";` though that makes it a bit less legible.

Also: do you really want to check if anything in the entire DOM has the userLocation class?  Perhaps you want something closer to `$(yourJqueryLocator).hasClass("userLocation")`?  This is also a bit more self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2-dimensional array of data, which contains the selector plus attribute-name plus the two attribute-values:

```
var elements = [
  ['header', 'href', '#nfl-city', '#city'],
  ['footer', 'title', '#nflcity', '#city'],
  ... etc ...
  ];
```

Then you can loop through this array, setting the attribute for each element to either the first or second value.

---

Furthermore if you can change the code elsewhere to expect a regular prefix (for example, `#nfl-` not `#nfl`) then you only need three elements in each array (one attribute value, e.g. `city`) and can loop through the array setting the attribute to the value plus the value's appropriate prefix (`#` or `#nfl-`).